# ipywidgets interactive_output does not return pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, ipywidgets

Why won't the `widgets.interactive_output` function return a dataframe -- e.g.

```py
def foo(param):
    return pd.DataFrame({'Z':[param,param], 'A': ['b', 'b']})

params = widgets.Dropdown(options= ['a','b'])

bar = widgets.interactive_output(foo, {'param' : params})
widgets.VBox([params, bar])
```

whereas `widgets.interact` will?

```py
bar = widgets.interact(foo, param =params)
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `display()` in your function foo like so:

```py
def foo(param):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Z':[param,param], 'A': ['b', 'b']})
    display(df)    
    return df
```

`widgets.interact` does not need this.